# Is it possible to look at defined length in a string

Tags: c#

Is there a way in c# to look at a defined number of char in a string?

meaning - 
I have the following number
`336-5010-0000-00-10` that needs to change to this number - `336-5993-0000-00-10`

I only want to check if the 2nd segment of numbers are between `2999` and `6000`

I am reading this data from a CSV, I just don't want this statement a million times

```
if (columns[0].Contains(“5010”)) columns[0] = columns[0].Replace(“5010”, @”5993”);
```

Comment: `"I just don't want this statement a million times"`... and that's how the concept of the *function* came to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to

1. split the string on the '-' character into a string[] called stringParts
2. convert stringParts[1] to an integer
3. perform validation of the integer value from step 2

```
string[] stringParts = columns[0].Split('-');
int valueOfConcern = Convert.ToInt32(stringParts[1]);
if (valueOfConcern >= 2999 && valueOfConcern <= 6000)
{
    //take your action
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string test = "336-5010-0000-00-10";
string foo = Regex.Replace(test, @"(\d+\-)(2999|[3-5][0-9]{3}|6000)((-\d+){3})", "${1}5993${3}");
```

Alternative crazy LINQ answer:

```
string foo2 = string.Join("-", from number in test.Split('-').Select((str, index) => new { str = str, index = index })
              let num = Convert.ToInt32(number.str)
              select number.index == 1 && num >= 2999 && num <= 6000 ? "5993" : number.str);
```

http://dotnetfiddle.net/yzROoK

Edit: More obvious regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
string numberStr = "336-5010-0000-00-10";
int number = int.Parse(numberStr.Substring(4, 4));
```

`numberStr.Substring(4, 4)` gives you only the four-digit number starting at the 4th character, which `int.Parse()` converts into a number.

Then you can test that `number` is between your specified range, replace it, etc.